# How to get all documents at once for a set of doc IDs, but only part of the properties in those docs, not the entire docs, in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to get all documents at once for a set of doc IDs, but only part of the properties in those docs, not the entire docs ?

This works to get all the docs at once:

```
const refs = selection.map(id => db.doc(`CollectionName/${id}`))
const request = await db.getAll(...refs)
```

So I tried this to retrieve only a few properties, but it does not work:

```
const refs = selection.map(id => db.doc(`CollectionName/${id}`).select("property1","property2"))
const request = await db.getAll(...refs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no way to get only specific fields for a list of document references. Calling `getAll` with a list of document references returns the full snapshots of those documents, and calling `select` to get a subset of the fields is only possible on a `Query` which you can't initialize with a set of document references.

I don't think this is an inherent limitation of the product though, so it might be worth it to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Frank :)

Comment: (feature request submitted)